# Does having the name of a country in the site HTML <title> based on geolocation hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, title, geolocation

My website detects where the visitor is coming from. If the visit is from Guatemala, the title is:

```html
<title>[Company name] | Discounts in Guatemala</title>
```

If the visit is from El Salvador, the title is:

```html
<title>[Company name] | Discounts in El Salvador</title>
```

I am doing this for SEO purposes. However, I am concerned about it because I am not sure how Google crawlers are going to interpret this. Will Google store `<title>[Company name] | Discounts in Guatemala</title>` and ignore `<title>[Company name] | Discounts in El Salvador</title>`, or vice versa? Will be equivalent to having a dynamic `<title>` and confuse Google about what `<title>` to use?

My goal is to rank high in Guatemala for the query `Discounts in Guatemala` and also rank high in El Salvador for the query `Discounts in El Salvador`. But I am not sure if I am following the right approach by using a dynamic `<title>` based on location, or if I am only confusing Google and maybe I should use this instead:

```html
<title>[Company name] | Discounts in El Salvador and Guatemala</title>
```

or

```html
<title>[Company name] | Discounts in Guatemala and El Salvador</title>
```

Comment: Changing the title tag depending upon where a person comes from is not a good idea. Instead, use both locations in the title tag or simply create two pages to rank well for two different locations. I suggest using mark-up if you do. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google uses [searchers](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en) from [multiple origins](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en) but most of them are located in USA. That means that Google will always see the same title:

```
<title>[Company name] | Discounts in USA</title>
```

In this situation, you will never be able to index nor rank for other countries cause searchers will never see those "located titles".

The correct approach to this situation must be a **solid and accessible language directory** supported with [hreflang tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: These are pages all on the same site and there's some common denominator between the discount pages you're creating.

In that case I would consider creating a folder that holds each page by the common denominator. So say you're selling vacation packages, I'd create that folder and then target each location supported with hreflang tags:

Vacation-packages/Discounts in Guatemala 
Vacation-packages/Discounts in El Salvador

Comment: I'll bet this isn't a travel related site.   Travel destinations are usually not popular for people currently in that location.   It still might make sense to have different local pages if you can have different content for each of them.